# (MK) universal class = von Neumann universe?

Tags: set-theory

I am studying MK set theory. By the axiom schema of class comprehension, which roughly states that

> Given a monadic predicate $\phi$ of MK, then there is a class $C = \{x: \phi(x)\}$,

the **universal class** $U = \{x: \exists y\; (x \in y)\}$ is definable in MK. It is the class of all sets.

I have a feeling that $U = V$ where $V$ denotes the **von Neumann universe**. But how can I prove it? Or, is it provable in MK?

Comment: You are correct, just do the standard [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_hierarchy) construction of $V$ and show that all sets $x\in U$ have some rank and therefore show up in $V$. This question would be better suited for MSE, so I’m voting to move it there.

Comment: @Alec Rhea thank you! I check that now!